# replacing GCSE with Bing custom search

Tags: bing, google-custom-search

Because Google is cancelling Google Custom Search Engine, I'm switching to Bing's similar service. Google provided a script like this:

```
<script>
 (function() {
   var cx = 'KEY';
   var gcse = document.createElement('script');
   gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
   gcse.async = true;
   gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +'//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
 })();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

Which I could use to display my results as an iframe. I liked this because it meant I didn't have to handle display, pagination etc. Does Bing provide anything similar or do I have to write it up on my own?

Answer (score 0):

Custom search does provide hosted UX and as a part of that it provides javascript snippet along with html endpoint. It is as a part of your instance creation in customsearch.ai.